# Image not loading for Carousel

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, carousel

I am trying to publish images in Carousel. But Image not loading. Anyone can help will be highly appreciated. Following is the code:

carousel_test.aspx file code below. Here , through Rgallery, I am trying to display carousel images.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="carousel_test.aspx.cs" Inherits="reader.carousel_test" %>



<!DOCTYPE html>


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<!--Carousel -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Carousel -->
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="font-size: small">


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">

<asp:Repeater ID="Rgallary" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="item" >
<div class="item active">
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("product_sell_code") %>' />
</div>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

</div>

//This is used for manual navigation like for next or previous
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel"   data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a> 
</div>

        </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 2500
        })
    });
</script>
```

carousel_test.aspx.cs file code below. This is code file, where I am calling for loading image from database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace reader
{
    public partial class carousel_test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string sq = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["readerConnStr"].ConnectionString;


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                bindslide();

            }
        }
        public void bindslide()
        {

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sq);

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select product_sell_code from product_for_sell ", connection))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                da.Fill(ds);
                Rgallary.DataSource = ds;
            }
            Rgallary.DataBind();

            connection.Dispose();
            connection.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

ImageHandler.ashx.cs  is the Image Handler File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace reader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for $codebehindclassname$
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["readerConnStr"].ToString());

       /* string strcon = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["readerConnStr"].ToString(); */
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string imageid = context.Request.QueryString["ImID"];
           /* SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strcon);*/
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select product_image from product_for_sell where product_sell_code=" + imageid, connection);
            SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);
            connection.Close();
            context.Response.End();
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the code. Please help**

Comment: by any chance you debugged the code? and caught this is place where it is not working as expected?

Comment: Yes, I debugged. But could not identify the place where its not working as expected

Comment: In your internet browser, open developer tools and go to Network tab. Can you see any error when you filter by url containing "ImageHandler.ashx" ?

Comment: @derloopkat , no error in browser network tab on url containing "ImageHandler.ashx"